# Yeoman, Gulp livereload fails on html5Mode

Tags: angularjs, gulp, yeoman, gulp-livereload

Im using yeoman with gulp, after i enable html5Mode on angular, livereload stop working, this is my current gulp connect code:

```
gulp.task('start:server', ['environment'], function() {
$.connect.server({
    root: [yeoman.app, yeoman.temp],
    host: ENVIRONMENT + '.localhost',
    livereload: true,
    fallback: 'index.html',
    port: 9001,
    middleware:function(connect, opt){
        return [
            modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']),
            connect.static('.tmp'),
            connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
            ),
            connect.static(yeoman.app)
        ];
    }
});
});
```

To enable html5Mode i use the following

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: true
}).hashPrefix('!');
```

i also have base url tag. I found a lot of information about grunt but no solutions for gulp connect. Hope someone else have any hints.

Comment: Is there an error message anywhere?

Comment: No errors on console, what i read from other similar problems is when the url is change from #/ to /, seems that livereload doesn't handle this very well, but in my case i can't find a solution, i just find solutions for grunt and no for gulp. Seen odd to me that anyone else is having this issue with gulp.

Comment: @AntonioAlarcon did you find a solution for this, I see to be having the same problem

Comment: I still have the issue, i'm living with it for the moment.